# Optimization: How to build a Windows.Data.Json JsonArray in a way that avoids array resizing?

Tags: c#, json

I have some working code that I would like to optimize that uses the Windows.Data.Json JsonArray object:

```
// This works but could be improved?

JsonArray inputArray;

...

// Filter the array
JsonArray filteredObjs = new JsonArray();
foreach (IJsonValue jsonValue in inputArray)
{
    JsonObject obj = jsonValue.GetObject();
    if (SomeFilterOperation(obj))
        filteredObjs.Add(entityObj); // Amortized O(1)
}

return filteredObjs;
```

The "Add" function is getting run over 10,000 times over the course of my code - not necessarily all in the same scope, but it still results in some long arrays. So this is a candidate for optimization.

Add is amortized O(1), but it would be nice to avoid the internal array resize operation when capacity gets exceeded. Since I know the maximum size of the `filteredObjs` is `inputArray.Count`, I tried making a list with a specified capacity so it wouldn't have to be resized:

```
var filteredObjs = new List<IJsonValue>(inputArray.Count);
foreach (IJsonValue jsonValue in inputArray)
{
    JsonObject obj = jsonValue.GetObject();
    if (SomeFilterOperation(obj))
        filteredObjs.Add(obj); // will never cause a resize, is thus O(1) always
}

return /* how to turn this List<IJsonValue> into a JsonArray? */
```

...but `JsonArray` doesn't have any constructor that accepts a `List<IJsonValue>`, which is frustrating because that's what a `JsonArray` is.

The main question:

Is there a way to convert `List<IJsonValue>` to `JsonArray` or build a `JsonArray` in a way that avoids resizing?

Comment: From the [MSDN page of JsonArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonarray(v=vs.95).aspx), it should work if you just use the constructor as: `return new JsonArray(filteredObjs);` or if it really needs an array you could do `return new JsonArray(filteredObjs.ToArray());`

Comment: If I try that, I get the error:

error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Data.Json.IJsonValue>' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'

or

error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Windows.Data.Json.IJsonValue[]' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'

Comment: Ah, then the problem is with conflicting namespaces, you're using `Windows.Data.Json` while I thought it was `Newtonsoft.Json;`

Comment: The closest I see is the `ReplaceAll` method, e.g. something like `var array = new JsonArray(); array.ReplaceAll(filteredObjs.ToArray());`. Not sure what  the implementation of `ReplaceAll` is doing though.

Comment: I'm actually getting confused with all the things called JsonArray. It also seems there is something called JArray... I'm not sure why my compiler is calling that out when I am using JsonArray not JArray.

Comment: @IvanStoev your suggestion results in "error CS1061: 'JsonArray' does not contain a definition for 'ReplaceAll'" - you may also be thinking of the incorrect JsonArray

Comment: I'm looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Data.Json)

Comment: Looks like ReplaceAll(IJsonValue[]) is "not implemented in C#" according to the page for JsonArray in your link

Comment: Update: I have determined there is no way to do what I want with Windows.Data.Json JsonArray. Apparently there is an alternative: Newtonsoft.Json JArray... but it doesn't look like that offers the ability to set capacities either.